# Calling remote ejb 3

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.1

When I call a remote ejb method in jboss 4.3, with parameters in String and return in Object Serializable, the following problem occurs below:

```
java.rmi.MarshalException: Failed to communicate.  Problem during marshalling/unmarshalling; nested exception is: 
    java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.security.provider.certpath.AdjacencyList
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.SocketClientInvoker.handleException(SocketClientInvoker.java:127)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.transport(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:658)
    at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.invoke(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:141)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:1858)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:718)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor.invoke(InvokeRemoteInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.security.SecurityClientInterceptor.invoke(SecurityClientInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessRemoteProxy.invoke(StatelessRemoteProxy.java:107)
    at $Proxy1.getDadosPedido(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.comprafacil.sondapagamentobraspag.pedido.BraspagDAO.getDadosPedidoWS(BraspagDAO.java:476)
    at br.com.comprafacil.sondapagamentobraspag.pedido.BraspagDAO.processaPedidoNullos(BraspagDAO.java:77)
    at br.com.comprafacil.sondapagamentobraspag.process.ControlBraspagProcess.processaPedidosNullos(ControlBraspagProcess.java:53)
    at br.com.comprafacil.sondapagamentobraspag.process.SondaPagamentoBraspagProcess.execute(SondaPagamentoBraspagProcess.java:16)
    at br.com.comprafacil.sondapagamentobraspag.main.SondaPagamentoBraspag.main(SondaPagamentoBraspag.java:44)
Caused by: java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.security.provider.certpath.AdjacencyList
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1309)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1908)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1832)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1719)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1305)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1908)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1832)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1719)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1305)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1908)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1832)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1719)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1305)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1908)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1832)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1719)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1305)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1908)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1832)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1719)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1305)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:348)
    at org.jboss.remoting.serialization.impl.java.JavaSerializationManager.receiveObjectVersion2_2(JavaSerializationManager.java:245)
    at org.jboss.remoting.serialization.impl.java.JavaSerializationManager.receiveObject(JavaSerializationManager.java:133)
    at org.jboss.remoting.marshal.serializable.SerializableUnMarshaller.read(SerializableUnMarshaller.java:120)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.versionedRead(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:914)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.transport(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:602)
    at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.invoke(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:141)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:1858)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:718)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor.invoke(InvokeRemoteInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.security.SecurityClientInterceptor.invoke(SecurityClientInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessRemoteProxy.invoke(StatelessRemoteProxy.java:107)
    at $Proxy1.getDadosPedido(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.comprafacil.sondapagamentobraspag.pedido.BraspagDAO.getDadosPedidoWS(BraspagDAO.java:476)
    at br.com.comprafacil.sondapagamentobraspag.pedido.BraspagDAO.processaPedidoNullos(BraspagDAO.java:77)
    at br.com.comprafacil.sondapagamentobraspag.process.ControlBraspagProcess.processaPedidosNullos(ControlBraspagProcess.java:53)
    at br.com.comprafacil.sondapagamentobraspag.process.SondaPagamentoBraspagProcess.execute(SondaPagamentoBraspagProcess.java:16)
    at br.com.comprafacil.sondapagamentobraspag.main.SondaPagamentoBraspag.main(SondaPagamentoBraspag.java:44)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor.invoke(InvokeRemoteInterceptor.java:74)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.security.provider.certpath.AdjacencyList
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1081)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1375)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1290)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1079)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1375)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:391)
    at java.lang.Throwable.writeObject(Throwable.java:649)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:917)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1339)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1290)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1079)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1375)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:391)
    at java.lang.Throwable.writeObject(Throwable.java:649)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:917)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1339)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1290)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1079)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1375)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1290)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1079)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1375)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1290)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1079)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:302)
    at org.jboss.remoting.serialization.impl.java.JavaSerializationManager.sendObjectVersion2_2(JavaSerializationManager.java:120)
    at org.jboss.remoting.serialization.impl.java.JavaSerializationManager.sendObject(JavaSerializationManager.java:95)
    at org.jboss.remoting.marshal.serializable.SerializableMarshaller.write(SerializableMarshaller.java:120)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.versionedWrite(ServerThread.java:861)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:642)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:407)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:174)"
```

Answer (score 0):

`NotSerializableException` says it all. Do all your parameters and return types in the remote interface implement Serialiazable?

Comment: Parameters are String and return is an Object Serializable.

Comment: Edit your question and provide the remote interface. Also include the class definition of the returned object.